# Как отключить всплывающие подсказки в visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, settings

Я хочу что-бы остались подсказки при написании, но что бы не было вплывающих подсказок при наведении, а то просто неудобно каждый рас курсор перемещать подальше
от текста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]